# How to put variable in a href on the vue js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I run this : `{{nextPage}}`

The result

http://chelseashop.dev/search-result?page=2

But when I put in a href like this :

```
<template>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            ...
            <li>
                <a :href="{{nextPage}}" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props:['total', 'data', 'nextPage', 'prevPage'],
        ...
    }
</script>
```

There exist error like this :

> template syntax error - invalid expression: :href="{{nextPage}}"

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-bind` expressions are directly executed as JavaScript. As such, they do not require interpolation.

You simply want

```
<a :href="nextPage" aria-label="Next">
```

See [Template Syntax - Attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes, instead use a [v-bind directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)