# building a hyperlink in a Vuetify Datatable - maybe v-bind?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm close to where I need to go but not close enough. This is my code

```
                 <td>
            <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/"
              {{item.pmid}} target="_blank">{{ item.pmid }}</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ item.year }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.authors }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.article }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.journal }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.rcr }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ item.percentile }}</td>
```

If I take out the href {{item.pmid}} it will go to the web page in a new window.  However I need to add the item.pmid value to the end of the href string so it will go to an exact page.  If I leave it the way it is now I get an error saying 'Element': '{{' is not a valid attribute name.  Is there someway that I can get the value concatenated to the string?

OK-- I've found this:
[How to put variable in a href on the vue js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949256/how-to-put-variable-in-a-href-on-the-vue-js-2)
But still not sure about how to us v-bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it--

```
           <td>
            <a
              :href="'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/' + item.pmid"
              target="_blank"
            >{{ item.pmid }}</a>
          </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this, if anyone is still wondering, is to use [dynamic rows](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#customizing-default-rows)

They work like this:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="tableHeaders"
    :items="tableItems"
>
  <template v-slot:item.link="{ item }">
    <a :href="item.link">Link</a>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```